# C# Inheritance Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, inheritance

Again, I'm fairly new at this sort of thing and perhaps the error message is telling me what it is and I'm simply not understanding, but... This code in anon.cs

```
namespace cheese.pies.org
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Xml;

    public class CasLogin : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private const string CasHost = "notimportant";

        public static string GetId()
        {
        }
}
```

Ends up giving me an error when referenced here:

```
<% @Page Language="C#" Inherits="CasLogin" CodeFile="CasLogin.cs" %>
<script language="C#" runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    String directoryId = CasLogin.GetId();
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(directoryId, false);
}
</script>
```

The error is on line one and is:

> Compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).

If I change it from

```
public class CasLogin : System.Web.UI.Page
```

to

```
public class CasLogin : Page
```

I get this error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Page' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Again, the error is telling you exactly what is wrong: *are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?*  - The answer is Yes.

Comment: You do have both of them in that cheese.pies.org namespace, right? Make sure all your namespaces are identical for these files.

Comment: Also, make sure your class is defined as partial if it uses code behind. e.g. public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I change it from `public class CasLogin : System.Web.UI.Page` to
>   `public class CasLogin : Page` I get this error

You are missing the correct `using` statement for the `Page` class (`System.Web.UI`) thus when you remove the full qualification the compiler can no longer find the `Page` class.

You should also fully-qualify the class name in the Page directive, i.e. `Inherits="cheese.pies.org.CasLogin"`

**Good**

```
<% @Page Language="C#" Inherits="cheese.pies.org.CasLogin" CodeFile="CasLogin.cs" %>
```

**Bad**

```
<% @Page Language="C#" Inherits="CasLogin" CodeFile="CasLogin.cs" %>
```

Per your comment regarding a missing `partial` modifier:

```
public class CasLogin : System.Web.UI.Page
```

Should be:

```
public partial class CasLogin : System.Web.UI.Page
```

This tells the compiler that the `CasLogin` class is defined in multiple files (which is the case with web forms; the designer file is separate from the code behind file).

If it still doesn't work, I suggest recreating the page and copying any relevant code into it. **Normally Visual Studio handles all of this automatically and this is a non-issue.**

Comment: Including this (`using System.Web.UI;`) on anon.cs does not change the error, unfortunately. Also if you look above, System.Web is used.

Comment: Page isn't in `System.Web`, it's in `System.Web.UI`.

Comment: Actually, the error becomes `ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).`

Comment: See my update and the other answers; you also need to fully qualify the base class name in the Page directive.

Comment: Alright, I have added the `using System.Web.UI;` and changed the page directive to `<% @Page Language="C#" Inherits="cheese.pies.org.CasLogin" CodeFile="anon.cs" %>` and have a new error. Well, sort of an old one. It now yells at me saying `Compiler Error Message: CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'cheese.pies.org.CasLogin'; another partial declaration of this type exists`.

Comment: Ah, now making it a partial class at least somewhat worked. However, now it doesn't recognise CASLogin saying `CS0103: The name 'CasLogin' does not exist in the current context` -_-;;. I hate OOP...

Comment: @user798080 - just recreate the page...all of this is handled automatically by Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm using gvim and I'm not on a Windows machine. I am, however, operating on a server that only has ASP.NET support. I'm... Not quite sure what you mean by 'recreate the page.'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10759/discussion-between-user798080-and-tim-medora)

Comment: I was referring to using Visual Studio to create a new page since it will set up references, class names, file structure, etc. automatically. If you aren't using VS then it's irrelevant.

Comment: I will post one final question. OOP isn't really my thing, so this is a bit difficult for me, I apologise. I seem to have imported it successfully, but I can't seem to access the class. Why can't we just have functions in header files and be happy...

Comment: "Access the class"? If you append your current problem to your original question I will take a look (hard to diagnose in comments/chat).

Comment: Well I had an issue where it didn't recognise CasLogin, but then I changed the line to `String directoryId = cheese.pies.org.CasLogin.GetId()` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it should be

```
<% @Page Language="C#" Inherits="cheese.pies.org.CasLogin" CodeFile="CasLogin.cs" %>
```

For the other error you can use

```
using System.Web.UI;

public class CasLogin : Page
```

Without fully qualifying the class name it doesn't know which Page you're talking about, so you can be explicit when you declare the class or you can use a using statement.  The first error is the same issue, it can't see the CasLogin class inside the chees.pies.org namespace

Answer (score 1):

inherits needs to be:

```
Inherits="cheese.pies.org.CasLogin"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at my own little test project/code, I see a few things noticably different: the "usings" come before the namespace declaration, and the use of **partial class** for code behind. Also, note that the Inherits has the fully qualified class (includes namespace).

in Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2._Default" %>
```

in Default.aspx.cs

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
```

Comment: Ordering of the usings/namespace doesn't matter but you are correct about the other items.